# Is the only way to update password stored in Keychain, to delete the old/existing stored password & re-add its new "update"?

Tags: password, keychain

If the only way to update a password stored in Keychain, is to delete its old/existing stored password & re-add its new update, then [steps like this show how](https://it.clas.ufl.edu/kb/changing-network-password-in-keychain/).

**But I'm curious if there is a way to update without first deleting the old stored password first?**  That is the case for most website/webapp passwords for example.  The extra step of deleting first in Keychain isn't a big deal, but it would be useful to know if that's truly the only way, or if instead I am missing something?

*Note:  I am *NOT* asking how to update the password to Keychain itself, but instead rather I'm asking about passwords stored *IN* Keychain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t test as I’m on my phone & don’t think I’ve ever tried on a network password, but for a web password you can simply open the item, reveal the existing pass, type a new one & save.

Comment: Seems you are right, yes.  I don't know why it seemed like that did not work on the old password I tried it on yesterday, but seems to work on the new one today at least. Accepting your Answer, but deleting my question as I see it is stupid now.  Thanks

Comment: Oh I can't now since it has been Answered I guess.